# Azure Bot Framework - ConnectionFailure: Malformed agent config message

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, botframework, hololens, mrtk

I am developing a Voice Assistant on the HoloLens 2 using Unity, MRTK and the Azure Bot Framework. I have followed this video [Made with MRTK: Bot Integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmv4cPZuh5k&t=1892s). In the editor the voice recognition works as expected. When I build the project as a debug build, it also works as expected. However, when I build the project as a Release build, the voice recognition functionality does not work any more. I get the following error message in the Release build:

Cancelled with reason: Error.
Error Reason: ConnectionFailure.
Error Message: Connection was closed by the remote host. Error code: 1002. Error details: Malformed agent config message. SessionId: *REDACTED*.

The code that creates the Dialog Service Connector is as follows:

```
private void CreateDialogServiceConnector()
    {
        Debug.Log($"creatDialogSerciveConnector enter");
        if (dialogServiceConnector == null )
        {
            if (subscriptionKey == string.Empty || region == string.Empty )
            {
                Debug.Log($"One or more input fields weren't provided. Check the fields in the Canvas object or in the script");
                throw new InvalidOperationException("DialogServiceConfig Creation Failed");
            }
            dialogServiceConfig = BotFrameworkConfig.FromSubscription(subscriptionKey, region,botID);
            dialogServiceConfig.Language = connectionLanguage;
            if (dialogServiceConfig == null)
            {
                Debug.Log($"One or more input fields weren't provided. Check the fields in the Canvas object or in the script");
                throw new InvalidOperationException("DialogServiceConfig Creation Failed");
            }
            AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
            dialogServiceConnector = new DialogServiceConnector(dialogServiceConfig, audioConfig);

            dialogServiceConnector.ActivityReceived += DialogServiceConnector_ActivityReceived;
            dialogServiceConnector.Canceled += DialogServiceConnector_Canceled;
            dialogServiceConnector.Recognized += DialogServiceConnector_Recognized;
        }

        stateIndicatorString = "DialogServiceConnector created";
        Debug.Log($"CreateDialogServiceConnector exit");
    }
```

Note that the botID variable is a empty string.

What i have tried so far:

I am expecting a ActivityReceivedEventArgs that contains the recognised result and some other information.

I tested the project in the Unity editor, where the behaviour worked as expected.

I then build the project as a ARM64 UWP Debug build in unity, in this build everything worked as expected too.

After that I tested the project as a unity ARM64 UWP Release build, this is where the issues arose. I did not receive any output.

I then tried running the project as a ARM32 build, in Release and Debug mode, but it yielded the same results.

Then I wrote the whole implementation of the Bot Framework according to the afformentioned video, which allowed me to get more insight in the error provided earlier. The error is only generated when building as a **Release Build**. In **a Debug Build** everything works as expected.

I searched on the internet for this error, but it did not get me far.

I hope somebody has an idea of what might be wrong.

EDIT: We are using the IL2CPP Scripting back-end

Comment: Can you advise what version of Unity that you are using?  It could be an IL2CPP optimization occurring during the compilation with stripping the release build only.  Optimizations do not occur during debug.  Example: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeStripping.html

Comment: @Nathan-MSFT I am using Unity 2021.3.17f1

Comment: Thanks.  For the botID being blank, is it blank  for both debug & release builds?  If it is blank only for the release builds, perhaps the configuration loading needs further review.  Maybe the configuration file is just not being deployed for release builds?

Comment: Hi, the botID is blank in both cases, but I will try some more varieties of the DialogServiceConfig and DialogServiceConnector. I will keep you updated.

Comment: @Nathan-MSFT I removed the botID variable from the config method. This results in the same behaviour. It works in the Debug build, but does not work in a Release build. It returns the same error.

Updating Unity from version 2021.3.17f to 2021.3.27 results in the same problems.

Comment: @Nathan-MSFT I also tested building as a Master build. But this returned the same 1002 error code and message.

Comment: @Nathan-MSFT 

I further tried to reduce code stripping, by including a [Preserve] tag above the class that handles the Speech.Dialog logic in my application. Additionally I added the following two lines to the generated link.xml file.

The lines added are as follows:
 <assembly fullname="Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech" preserve="all" ignoreIfMissing="1"/>
 <assembly fullname="Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Dialog" preserve="all" ignoreIfMissing="1"/>

Unfortunately, implementing these two changes had no effect on the bug. So it still remains to be fixed.